# ReferenceError: require is not defined in javascript

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

I am html javascript beginner and i simply have to read the contents of a text file at a location and store each column in that file in an array (there are 3 columns) in html and i use javascript to do so.

I have came across 2 errors http://prntscr.com/6ilvhx :

(1)ReferenceError: require is not defined

(2) ReferenceError: readfile is not defined

My code to do this is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
        console.log("just a check1");
        var fs = require('fs');
        console.log("just a check2");

        function readLines(input, done) {
            var arr = [];
            var remaining = '';

            input.on('data', function (data) {
                remaining += data;
                var index = remaining.indexOf('\n');
                while (index > -1) {
                    var line = remaining.substring(0, index);
                    remaining = remaining.substring(index + 1);
                    func(line);
                    index = remaining.indexOf('\n');
                }
            });

            input.on('end', function () {
                if (remaining.length > 0) {
                    func(remaining);
                    done(arr);
                }
            });

            function func(data) {
                arr.push(data.split(/\s+/g));
            }
        }

        var input = fs.createReadStream('Content\TextFile\distinctGimeiNo.txt');
        readLines(input, done);

        function done(arr) {

            var obj = {};
            var key1 = arr[0][0];
            var key2 = arr[0][1];
            var key3 = arr[0][3];
            obj[key1] = [];
            obj[key2] = [];
            obj[key3] = [];

            arr.shift();

            arr.forEach(function (item) {
                obj[key1].push(item[0]);
                obj[key2].push(item[1]);
                obj[key3].push(item[2]);
            });

            console.log('X:', obj['X']);
            console.log('Y:', obj['Y'])
            console.log('Z:', obj['Z'])
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>    
</body>
</html>
```

How to make it work ?I found this on debugging http://prntscr.com/6ilvhx

Updated code : (after adding library)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js>

        console.log("just a check1");
        var fs = require('fs');
        console.log("just a check2");
        function readlines(input, done) {
            var arr = [];
            var remaining = '';
            input.on('data', function (data) {
                remaining += data;
                var index = remaining.indexOf('\n');
                while (index >
        -1) {
                    var line = remaining.substring(0, index);
                    remaining = remaining.substring(index + 1);
                    func(line);
                    index = remaining.indexOf('\n');
                }
            });

            input.on('end', function () {
                if (remaining.length > 0) {
                    func(remaining);
                    done(arr);
                }
            });

            function func(data) {
                arr.push(data.split(/\s+/g));
            }
        }

        var input = fs.createReadStream('Content\TextFile\distinctGimeiNo.txt');
        readLines(input, done);

        function done(arr) {

            var obj = {};
            var key1 = arr[0][0];
            var key2 = arr[0][1];
            var key3 = arr[0][2];
            obj[key1] = [];
            obj[key2] = [];
            obj[key3] = [];

            arr.shift();

            arr.forEach(function (item) {
                obj[key1].push(item[0]);
                obj[key2].push(item[1]);
                obj[key3].push(item[2]);
            });

            console.log('X:', obj['X']);
            console.log('Y:', obj['Y'])
            console.log('Z:', obj['Z'])
        }
    </script>



</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which libraries do you use? in your code, there is no reference to them - how should the browser include em, if he don't knows about em...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible to use node.js script in your browser, start it with node.. :)

You can use jQuery for do that in client side :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
     console.log("just a check1");
     $.ajax({
         type:'GET',
         url:'./hello.txt',
         dataType: 'text',
      }).success(function (data){
               s = data.substr(32);
               var s2 = s.replace(/\r\n/g," ");
               var array = s2.split(' ');

               var col1 =[];
               var col2 =[];
               var col3 =[];
               var j=0;
               for(var i = 0; i <= array.length-3; i=i+3){
                       col1[j]=array[i];
                       col2[j]=array[i+1];
                       col3[j]=array[i+2];
                       j++;
               };

               console.log(col1,col2, col3);
      })
 </script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>//hello world !</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

$.ajax allow you to get back datas with a specify url.
Normally,that do that you wanted

Comment: please explain a bit more in detail.. I am new to javascript (switched from c++) . How to do and what to do to make it work ?

Comment: Sorry ^^, you use a script for server-side in client side. i think it's impossible, you need to create file (ex : server.js) and put your lines into this file. Then you need to launch shell and launch your server file with that command : node server.js       (If you don't have node.js, you must download it)

Comment: Actually i have no idea about client and server side. I have just switched from C++ . I am just added a html page and run it in browser. But could u please let me know Ho to make it work. I have to read a file and store its contnt in arrays. Is it poasible how to do that.

Comment: Oki, here you can use javascript for client and not node.js script (for server), try this :    
        $.ajax({
            url: "path",
            success: function (data){
                var obj = data; console.log(obj.color) //example
            }
        });

Comment: You need to include <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script> in your html

Comment: Thanks for the answer . One thing i observe is  console.log("just a check1"); never printed because i guess teh code written in <script> code </script> is not invoked. How to invoke it. Please also update your anser so that i will be able to mark it. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73306/discussion-between-kalho-and-charly).